# Best way to get a biased selection from a file using python

Tags: python

Is there a better way to write this code? It reads a text file (specified when called) the first line contains weighting factors for the file. Weighting factors apply to the first lines of the file and are always less than or equal to the number of items in the file, a weight of 1 is assigned to any other items. It then chooses one or more lines from the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
from sys import argv

action = argv[1]
repetition = int(argv[2])

def fileopen(a,b):                              
    with open(a,"r") as f:
        b = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]
    return b

#strips new lines, returns list

action = fileopen(action+".txt",action) 

#passes argv[1] to fileopen        

weight = action.pop(0)                          
weight = (weight.split(","))                    
for j in range(len(weight)):
    weight[j] = int(weight[j])                  
for y in range(len(action)-len(weight)):        
    weight.append(1)                            

#assigns weighting to a list and pads it with 1s if needed.

for k in range(repetition):                     
    print(random.choices(action,weight))
```